# Python GUI frame and button layout, how to add frame and buttons to correct location?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def create_layout(frame):

frame = Frame(frame, bg = 'red')
frame.pack(side = LEFT, fill=BOTH)

b = Button(frame, text='Button1', command=pressed, padx = 20)
b.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
c = Button(frame, text='Button2', command=pressed, padx=20)
c.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
```

I got this code so far, assume that from Tkinter import * has already been called and the frame has already had its size and colour set. It should look like the picture below. However i can't ever get button 3 and 4 to the frame on the right, whenever i add a button it goes in the red frame.

[image]

Comment: You don't show the code that creates the yellow frame, button3 and button4, so we can only guess about what you're doing wrong.

Comment: the yellow part is preset from the tkinter import, i don't even know the code for it. However when i try to get buttons in to the right side, i get these error:
Wrong: you need to expand your frame (to 1).
Wrong: exactly two of the buttons need to be children of the given frame.
Wrong: exactly two of the buttons need to be children of the given frame.
        frame1= Frame(frame)

    d = Button(frame1, text='Button3', command=pressed)
    d.pack()

    e = Button(frame1, text='Button4', command=pressed)
    e.pack()
thats what i added into the function, to get those errors

Comment: Those "Wrong:..." messages aren't standard Tkinter error messages. Are you running some other sort of program to run your code?

Comment: Yes this is kinda a homework i am stuck at and i just can't get the last bit working. i can't use root as it give me a syntx error. i have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the first set of buttons, button 1 & 2 are in the "frame", buttons 3 & 4 should be left out.

So with buttons 1 & 2, open the frame with the bg of red, pack it with side=tk.LEFT, fill with both & expand it.

With buttons 3 & 4, just side them LEFT and expand.  That will work like a treat ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another frame that sits to the right, and then pack button3 and button4 into that. Maybe change the previous frame you have there to frame1 and then have:

```
frame2 = Frame(frame, bg = "yellow")
frame2.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
```

Then, create the buttons and pack them in. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 frames, and 4 buttons.

Let us create a function called `create_widgets()` which will only consist in calling 2 other functions `create_frames()` and `create_buttons()`

For the frames, we use the [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) layout manager:

```
def create_frames(self):
   self.left_frame = tk.Frame(width=140, height=140, background='red')       
   self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

   self.right_frame = tk.Frame(width=300, height=140, background='gold2')       
   self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

This will create this interface:

[image]

Let us design `create_buttons()` in a way it only consists in calling to 2 different functions, each having a specific task:

- `create_left_frame_buttons()` to create buttons for the left frame
- `create_right_frame_buttons()` to create buttons for the right frame

Here is their simple implementation:

```
def create_buttons(self):
   self.create_left_frame_buttons()
   self.create_right_frame_buttons()       

def create_left_frame_buttons(self):
   self.button1 = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text='Button1')       
   self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

   self.button2 = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text='Button2')       
   self.button2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)       

def create_right_frame_buttons(self):
   self.button1 = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text='Button3')       
   self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=50)

   self.button2 = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text='Button4')       
   self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=70)
```

Note that I used the options `padx` and `pady` to create a suitable spacing between the buttons.

Up to this moment, this is the resulting interface:

[image]

You can see both the left and right frames are shrinking, and the result is ugly. To fix this issue, we can set  `rid_propagate(0)` for each frame.

So based on these observations and following [*Tkinter best practices*](https://www.begueradj.com/tkinter-best-practices.html), here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, master):
       self.master = master
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
       self.configure_gui()
       self.create_widgets()

   def configure_gui(self):
       self.master.title('Simple layout')
       self.master.geometry('440x140')
       self.master.resizable(0, 0)

   def create_widgets(self):
       self.create_frames()
       self.create_buttons()

   def create_frames(self):
       self.left_frame = tk.Frame(width=140, height=140, background='red')
       self.left_frame.grid_propagate(0)
       self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

       self.right_frame = tk.Frame(width=300, height=140, background='gold2')
       self.right_frame.grid_propagate(0)
       self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)   

   def create_buttons(self):
       self.create_left_frame_buttons()
       self.create_right_frame_buttons()       

   def create_left_frame_buttons(self):
       self.button1 = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text='Button1')       
       self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

       self.button2 = tk.Button(self.left_frame, text='Button2')       
       self.button2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)       

   def create_right_frame_buttons(self):
       self.button1 = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text='Button3')       
       self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=50)

       self.button2 = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text='Button4')       
       self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=70)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = tk.Tk()
   main_app =  MainApplication(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, i tried to run you code, but i got this error message: "cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack". Why i have this error? Thank you